# How to get data from modal?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to display the name of checked social media in Parent.
When modal click 'create' button and the checked social media will show in Parent.

here my modal :

```js
<template>
      <modal :show.sync="modals.classic" name="edit-button-modal" :width="400"  headerClasses="justify-content-center">
         <div class="modal-content">
          <form>
            <div class="custom-modal-header">
              <div class="custom-modal-wrapper">
                <h4>Social Media</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-modal-content">
              <div class="custom-modal-wrapper">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label><b>Choose:</b> </label>
                    <div style="margin-left: 17px;">
                      <span>Checked names: {{ checkedSocialMedia }}</span>
                      <div v-for="social in socialMedia">
                        <p-checkbox v-model="checkedSocialMedia" :id="social.name" :value="social.name" style="color: #52a0d2">
                          {{ social.name }}
                        </p-checkbox>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label>Style: </label>
                    <br>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" checked> Circle</label>
                      <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid grey; margin: 5px;">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"> Square</label>
                      <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid grey; margin: 5px; border-radius: 100px;">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-modal-footer">
              <div class="custom-modal-wrapper">
                <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" @click="addSocialMedia" type="button" >Create</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </modal>
</template>

<script>
    // import {DropDown} from 'src/components';
    export default {
      name: 'EditButtonModal',
      props: ["value"],
      data(){
        return {
            socialMedia: [
            {
              name: "Facebook"
            },
            {
              name: "Twitter"
            },
            {
              name: "LinkedIn"
            },
            {
              name: "Line"
            },
            {
              name: "WhatsApp"
            }
          ],
          // unchecked: false,
          checkedSocialMedia : [],
          modals: {
            classic: false
          }
        }
      },
      methods : {
        addSocialMedia (event) {
          this.$emit('modal-event', this.checkedSocialMedia);
          console.log(this.checkedSocialMedia)
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

I don't know how to capture data from modal and I want to show in Parent

```js
<template>
  <edit-button-modal></edit-button-modal>
  //want to show the data
<template>

import EditButtonModal from './EditButtonModal.vue'

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
       editButtonModal () {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.$modal.show('edit-button-modal')
        })
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

is it possible to get the data? or indeed my way is wrong. Please help

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: where your answer ?

Comment: sorry, i think someday i deleted it accidentally, now it's available